# Marking/commenting Matlab code?

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to mark Matlab code (in Matlab) via some kind of add-on? I'm looking for something similar to what Microsoft Word has with its "Review" mode where you can highlight a certain phrase/section and make a comment on the side. When I say "comment", I don't mean the regular code comments that you do with "%" in Matab.

I've googled for this, but I couldn't find anything. Anyone know if something like this exists that I may have missed? It would really help me when I'm reading someone else's code and I have to keep track of things / make comments for certain lines. Even if commenting isn't possible, it would be nice to be able to highlight certain lines via some kind of "highlighter" like the one in Word.

Comment: I'm not aware of any Matlab editor add-ons that will alow you to do this. The problem is that any implementation of this would be IDE specific - a dangerous route to go down in coding.

Comment: Ok, that's understandable. Figured I'd ask to make sure I wasn't missing anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This isn't possible.

In fact, most editors and IDEs (if not ALL of them) that I know don't even support this feature as each IDE will have to be specific in the way this is implemented (à la Trojanian).  The only thing that I can think of is if you print out the code in PDF, then use bubbles within the PDF viewer to tack on your comments.

However, if you want to highlight a specific line in your editor, you'll have to set this up in your settings.  Go to preferences, then in the `Editor / Debugger` options, choose the `Display` option, then choose `Highlight Current Line`.  Choose whichever colour you see fit.  I'm running MATLAB R2013a on Mac OS, and this is the window I get:

[image]

You'll see the `Highlight Current Line` feature.  Change that to whichever colour you want.  I have it as gray because I do like having the current line highlighted.

Comment: I just enabled highlighting the current line, and I love it. Thanks for the tip!